# R, rtools and rpy2

Tags: python, r, rpy2

Here is my setup. I installed R-3.2.0 from source using `./configure --enable-R-shlib --enable-R-static-lib --enable-BLAS-shlib --prefix=/home/fpinto` then `make && make install`. That's because I don't have root privileges. After that, I installed python-2.7.14 from source, and setuptools-38.2.4 and pip-9.0.1 from the sources. Everything was suppossed to be fine and I could use `python2 -m pip install` to install locally any package. Finally, I installed rtools with the last command.

However, when I try to import rtools the output is

```
Python 2.7.14 (default, Dec 20 2017, 01:10:08) 
[GCC 5.3.1 20160406 (Red Hat 5.3.1-6)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import rtools
/home/fpinto/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rpy2-2.8.6-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/rpy2/rinterface/__init__.py:186: RRuntimeWarning: Error in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...) : 
  unable to load shared object '/home/fpinto/lib64/R/library/stats/libs/stats.so':
  libRlapack.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

  warnings.warn(x, RRuntimeWarning)
/home/fpinto/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rpy2-2.8.6-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/rpy2/rinterface/__init__.py:186: RRuntimeWarning: During startup - 
  warnings.warn(x, RRuntimeWarning)
/home/fpinto/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rpy2-2.8.6-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/rpy2/rinterface/__init__.py:186: RRuntimeWarning: Warning message:
  warnings.warn(x, RRuntimeWarning)
/home/fpinto/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rpy2-2.8.6-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/rpy2/rinterface/__init__.py:186: RRuntimeWarning: package ‘stats’ in options("defaultPackages") was not found 
  warnings.warn(x, RRuntimeWarning)`
```

Looking for a solution, people posted to look for `R CMD ldd /home/fpinto/lib64/R/library/stats/libs/stats.so` with the output:

```
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffd56bd1000)
libRlapack.so => /home/fpinto/lib64/R/lib/libRlapack.so (0x00007f509d1fe000)
libRblas.so => /home/fpinto/lib64/R/lib/libRblas.so (0x00007f509cfd0000)
libgfortran.so.3 => /usr/lib64/libgfortran.so.3 (0x00007f509cc93000)
libm.so.6 => /usr/lib64/libm.so.6 (0x00007f509c991000)
libquadmath.so.0 => /usr/lib64/libquadmath.so.0 (0x00007f509c754000)
libR.so => /home/fpinto/lib64/R/lib/libR.so (0x00007f509c19a000)
libgomp.so.1 => /usr/lib64/libgomp.so.1 (0x00007f509bf74000)
libpthread.so.0 => /usr/lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f509bd57000)
libc.so.6 => /usr/lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007f509b996000)
libgcc_s.so.1 => /usr/lib64/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f509b780000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f509d861000)
libreadline.so.6 => /usr/lib64/libreadline.so.6 (0x00007f509b539000)
libpcre.so.1 => /usr/lib64/libpcre.so.1 (0x00007f509b2d8000)
liblzma.so.5 => /usr/lib64/liblzma.so.5 (0x00007f509b0b2000)
libbz2.so.1 => /usr/lib64/libbz2.so.1 (0x00007f509aea1000)
libz.so.1 => /usr/lib64/libz.so.1 (0x00007f509ac8b000)
librt.so.1 => /usr/lib64/librt.so.1 (0x00007f509aa83000)
libdl.so.2 => /usr/lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f509a87e000)
libicuuc.so.50 => /usr/lib64/libicuuc.so.50 (0x00007f509a505000)
libicui18n.so.50 => /usr/lib64/libicui18n.so.50 (0x00007f509a107000)
libtinfo.so.5 => /usr/lib64/libtinfo.so.5 (0x00007f5099edc000)
libicudata.so.50 => /usr/lib64/libicudata.so.50 (0x00007f5098908000)
libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f50985ff000)
```

Could you help me to figure it out what is going on?

Comment: `--enable-R-shlib --enable-R-static-lib ` seems wrong. Pick one.

Comment: I previously compile R using `--enable-R-shlib` but importing rtools gives the same output

Comment: Sorry, what is "import rools" ? Are you by chance confusing `rtools` and `rpy2` ?

Comment: I don't. However I also have problems with rpy2 installed from source. I'm trying to use pymeigo (python) which calls MEIGOR (a bioconductor package). Because pymeigo calls rtools, and rtools is only compatible with python2 (because a syntax error) I installed rpy2 from source (because most updated version is incompatible with python2) and so on.

Comment: could it be the PATH that rtools look for R packages?

Comment: I decided to start over, removing everything and installing again from source. This time worked perfectly, so the problem was a persistent misconfiguration. BTW, at the end, I need to add `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/fpinto/R-3.2.0/lib64/R/lib` to .bashrc to find libR.so when importing rpy2. Thank you for your time

Answer (score 0):

Configured again R using `--enable-R-shlib --enable-BLAS-shlib --enable-LAPACK-shlib --prefix=$HOME/R-3.2.0 && make && make install`.

Then I installed python2.7 and python3.6 from source configuring with `./configure --prefix=$HOME/python-2.7.14 && make && make install`. Finally, installed python packages using a source tar or pip.